# Azure DevOps (On Premise) - Minimatch Pattern To Download Multiple Parts of an Artifact

Tags: azure, build, azure-devops, release, artifact

I have a build artifact that I'm using as part of my release, that looks like this(Each line representing a different section/publish step of my build):

> MainSolution
>
> ExtraProject2
>
> ExtraProject3
>
> Database

So a bunch of different sections that I want to release in various forms. In my release, I'd like to only pull down the specific section I want to deploy, so I've created a "Download Build Artifact" step that looks like the following:

[image]

And it works great, pulls down all the file from just the "Database" section just fine:

```
2019-04-03T18:14:38.4325674Z Downloading Database/dbo/Tables/tbl_Core_Report_Subscription_Frequency_Time.sql to C:\TFSAgent4\_work\r5\a\DevelopmentVersionBuild\Database\dbo\Tables\tbl_Core_Report_Subscription_Frequency_Time.sql
2019-04-03T18:14:38.4338012Z Downloading Database/dbo/Tables/tbl_Core_Report_Style_Attribute_Exploded.sql to C:\TFSAgent4\_work\r5\a\DevelopmentVersionBuild\Database\dbo\Tables\tbl_Core_Report_Style_Attribute_Exploded.sql
2019-04-03T18:14:38.4342104Z Downloaded Database/dbo/Tables/tbl_Core_Report_Subscription.sql to C:\TFSAgent4\_work\r5\a\DevelopmentVersionBuild\Database\dbo\Tables\tbl_Core_Report_Subscription.sql
```

But in the next case, when I change the "Matching pattern" to pull down multiple sections, something like this:

```
Database/**|MainSolution/**
```

Now everything is skipped...

```
2019-04-03T18:23:24.9968583Z Total Files: 175, Processed: 0, Skipped: 175, Failed: 0, Download time: 4.397 secs, Download size: 0Bytes
2019-04-03T18:23:25.7209450Z Total Files: 227, Processed: 0, Skipped: 227, Failed: 0, Download time: 5.12 secs, Download size: 0Bytes
2019-04-03T18:23:25.7745591Z Total Files: 229, Processed: 0, Skipped: 229, Failed: 0, Download time: 5.175 secs, Download size: 0Bytes
2019-04-03T18:23:25.8355572Z Total Files: 175, Processed: 0, Skipped: 175, Failed: 0, Download time: 5.236 secs, Download size: 0Bytes
2019-04-03T18:23:25.9305217Z Total Files: 2146, Processed: 0, Skipped: 2146, Failed: 0, Download time: 5.334 secs, Download size: 0Bytes
```

Why is this the case? It seems like adding the "|" OR condition, breaks this step. I thought [that condition was supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts)? I've used it in other steps to do different things without issue. Is there another way to accomplish this without creating multiple "Download Build Artifact" steps?

Comment: Just add each pattern on its own line and remove the `|` altogether. The `|` is only supported with the `[?*@+!](pattern|pattern)` and can't span multiple levels of the file system.

Comment: @jessehouwing huh, so simple :) seems to work great though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @jessehouwing suggested I did the following:

[image]

This will then download multiple parts of my artifact.